# Filling a matrix within foreach with prespecified number of cores

Tags: r, foreach, parallel.foreach

When I run the following code

```
library(doParallel)

n <- 100
n_rep <- 10
MM <- array(0, dim = c(n_rep,2))

set.seed(12345678)
res <- foreach( sml = 1:n_rep, .combine = 'c'  )%dopar%
  {
    X <- cbind(rnorm(n), rnorm(n)) 
    MM[sml,] <- colMeans(X)
    res <- list(MM)
    return(res)
  }
registerDoSEQ()
res[n_rep]
```

I get

```
[[1]]
             [,1]         [,2]
 [1,] -0.07927541  0.141971071
 [2,]  0.06443829 -0.053686746
 [3,]  0.35348693  0.079771715
 [4,] -0.15080328  0.039228709
 [5,] -0.02202971  0.004544454
 [6,]  0.21505184  0.102926773
 [7,]  0.10736964 -0.103377088
 [8,]  0.01214953  0.084428114
 [9,] -0.10305094  0.055477455
[10,] -0.15185766 -0.003602193
```

This is what I want to have. However, I want to control the number of cores such that

```
library(doParallel)

n <- 100
n_rep <- 10

num_core <- 4
cl <- makeCluster(num_core)
registerDoParallel(cl)
on.exit(stopCluster(cl))

MM <- array(0, dim = c(n_rep,2))

set.seed(12345678)
res <- foreach( sml = 1:n_rep, .combine = 'c'  )%dopar%
  {
    X <- cbind(rnorm(n), rnorm(n)) 
    MM[sml,] <- colMeans(X)
    res <- list(MM)
    return(res)
  }
registerDoSEQ()
res[n_rep]
```

Unfortunately, by running this code, I get

```
[[1]]
             [,1]         [,2]
 [1,]  0.00000000  0.000000000
 [2,] -0.04088736  0.054177509
 [3,]  0.00000000  0.000000000
 [4,]  0.00000000  0.000000000
 [5,]  0.00000000  0.000000000
 [6,] -0.14591851  0.029542600
 [7,]  0.00000000  0.000000000
 [8,]  0.06478407 -0.004580664
 [9,]  0.00000000  0.000000000
[10,] -0.04621458  0.085551408
```

Some results are not stored. I'm wondering what is happening and how I can get the results as above with cntoroled number of cores.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Your `foreach` code has a side effect (subassignment into `MM`). Such side effects don't work if you parallelize. Your first attempt works because isn't parallelized because you didn't register a parallel backend.

Comment: Do you mean that it is not possible to fill in a matrix with parallel foreach?

Comment: No, it's not possible "to fill in a matrix" in parallel. It's also not necessary. You can calculate the elements of the matrix and have `foreach` combine them into a matrix (using the `.combine` argument, e.g., in your example, by passing `rbind` to it).

Comment: Thanks. But if there are many vectors of different sizes, reshaping it into one vector is tedious when `.combine=rbind` is used. (I have about 200 components in one replication...) I'm wondering how R users do Monte Carlo simulation with paralell when there are many computed objects during the replications.

Comment: They use lists.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use list, but could not get what I want. Could you tell how I can use list? Just to replace `res <- list(MM)` with `res <- list(colMeans(X))`?

Comment: You can absolutely not do `MM[sml,] <- colMeans(X)` and expect it to change `MM` in the global environment if your run the code in parallel. The parallel workers don't have access to the global environment.